# Issue with permissioned access using state address field

Tags: permissions

We are using the state field in the address to control access for our State leaders. The people in Florida can only view Florida contacts, Texas can only view Texas, etc.

My guy in Texas is in the process of adding a couple dozen contacts and memberships, and every third or fourth entry he is unable to pull the contact up even though he entered the address and the state field is marked Texas. I have system wide permissions so I can pull the contact up and see that it was entered and saved properly.

I've tried a couple of different things with him checking after each change, and it appears if I delete Texas from the address field and add it back he can then view the record.

We are using smart groups for the contacts - if the contact is marked Texas in the address field it gets added to the Texas contacts smart group. He is the Edit Texas group which gives him edit access to the Texas contacts smart group.

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to fix it? I've had similar complaints from others after the fact and we end up with duplicate entries because they end up creating a new contact that they are able to view. This is the first time where someone reached out and i was able to trouble shoot it in real time to get an idea of what is happening...

Matt Nye
Drupal 7.33/CiviCRM 4.6.4

Comment: Could it be that the contact is not added to the smart group immediatly? Also a smart group is rebuild in the background with a scheduled job.

Comment: Hi Jaap, that is exactly what it was. There is apparently (sometimes) a couple minute lag between the time the contact is entered and the time it is added to the requisite smart group. He was basically getting "ahead" of the system.

Comment: @JaapJansma - seems you have successfully answered the question, so maybe worth posting this as an answer? That way, you get the credit and the question is no longer listed as unanswered - everyone's a winner!
The smart group cache timeout is configurable: see http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/smart-groups/ under "Smart group caching".

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that the contact is not added to the smart group immediatly? Also a smart group is rebuild in the background with a scheduled job.

The smart group cache timeout is configurable: see http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/smart-groups under "Smart group caching".